# Can I provide a reason when I reject edits as the owner?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

There are quite a few meta questions from the editor's perspective regarding rejected edits, but as an owner I recently rejected one:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17761181

I would like to have been able to add a comment as to *why* it was rejected. My reasoning is that I had laid it out in CSV format and the editor changed it to a weird combination of commas and spacing.

I know I can choose to reject an edit... but sometimes a little clarity can go a long way in keeping harmony throughout the Stack Overflow ecosystem.

Is there a recommended way of informing them as to my intentions, or should it be left as an unexplained rejection (or did I miss something entirely)?

Comment: *"I know it's my right to do whatever to I like to my question"* that is actually  not true. You're not free to revert edits that objectively improve or clarify your posts, we settle rollback wars in favor of the editor all the time. We also don't allow you to delete (or destructively edit) your post once it has received good answers.

Comment: @meagar. I *didn't* know that... but thanks for the clarification: I'll reword the Q somewhat so that it doesn't become an issue.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to need to add a comment to this, the data is clearly meant to be comma separated values, not only that but the editor failed to remove the comma after *Time*, it shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: For anyone who knows what a CSV is that edit is, indeed, very strange... I'd reject it as *"vandalism"*. Maybe (just maybe) the editor thought it was a TSV (specially because of the *"Comment: aligned table"*), but even in that case the first comma should be removed. Every now and then I see people with high RP approving harmful edits in my answers, it's quite frustrating. We always expect people with high RP being a bit more careful...

Comment: This should be a feature-request, no? I'd like to see a response from OPs rejecting a suggested edit of mine (at least if the two other reviewers approved it)

Comment: @NVZ I believe it's already possible to ping editors using `@name` syntax in a standard comment on the post

Comment: @NickA You can certainly ping editors of accepted edits, but I don't think it works if the edit was rejected.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes but in the edits in question they *are* accepted, just rolled back afterwards, so the edit is still in the edit history (and so still pingable?)

Comment: @NickA Yes, in that case pinging should work. Although you have to type the whole username, it won't auto-complete.

Comment: @PM2 It won't auto complete but you only need to enter the first 3 characters of a name for a ping, as shown

Comment: One of the reject reasons in Suggested Edit Review queues is "Clearly Conflicts with the Author's Interest". Quietly decline the edit. If the user persists with making unwanted edits, either @ call them out and explain the situation, or flag your post with a Custom Flag and explain the situation to a moderator. Usually after the first reject, users don't bother pursuing the matter. If OP rejected an edit, they rejected an edit. That doesn't mean to say you should frown upon attempts to objectively improve your post.

Answer (score 11):

Leave a comment on your own post describing your reason. That's [what I've done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805664/force-one-of-two-python-class-attributes-to-be-always-be-assigned-a-value/16805778#comment24222769_16805778) in the past when undoing someone's edits. You [can ping the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments#comment353285_129236) if you want, but they'll probably see it anyway if they bother to monitor the post. This will also put it in a place for others to see if they consider making the same edit.

You may also want to consider some edits yourself to remove any ambiguity or reduce the chance of confusion. In your specific case, you could add something along the lines of,

> It's important that the values be comma separated in a single column.

or some other clarifying details about what aspects of your requested format are important to you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm a fan of that kind of system. It reads a little strangely when you're just reading the Q&A as a normal user... but it seems there's no particular way to do it better: other than @ mentioning the person, as @nick-a suggested above.

Comment: @cmroanirgo Doesn’t @-mentioning work on rejected edits? I have done this in the past and I *thought* it worked but I have no way of actually verifying. At any rate, that’s the solution I would have suggested.

Comment: [Everyone involved in the revision history is pingable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments#comment353285_129236) @KonradRudolph

Comment: @cmroanirgo Comments are disposable sticky notes. They're not suppose to be the same level of writing/reading quality as a question or answer post. Leaving a note about the history is a good use of them.